# Accessible popovers for additional help information

Tags: javascript, html, dom, accessibility, wai-aria

**tl;dr:** How would I implement an accessible popover? (I'm using bootstrap at the moment, but open to any ideas)

One of the biggest accessibility problems I face is the use of popovers when providing extra help information.

The way I understand it, popovers (and I guess more broadly, modals) are used for extra information when a tooltip cannot suffice. Popovers require the user to "open/click/activate" a help button for a new DOM element to be appended (or otherwise displayed), with the help information. While tooltips passively shows/speaks information whenever a user focuses the element. The tooltip widget itself is [still being considered by WAI-ARIA](https://github.com/w3c/aria-practices/issues/128)

Say I have a text-input field with a label. I want to attach supplementary content to that input, in the form of a clickable/actionable button. 
Initially I had the popover button in the label, before finding out the hard way that label's can't have block-level child elements.

I'm aware this probably isn't the best way of implementing an accessible popover. Here is my help button:

```
<div class="facs-ctl-help">
    <a role="button" aria-label="Show help for Template Id 2,003" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" title="">
        <span class="fa fa-info btn-floating waves-effect facs-help-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and here is my popover:

```
<div class="popover tooltip-help" role="tooltip">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 tabindex="-1">
        <i class="fa fa-info btn-floating waves-effect facs-help-icon"></i>Help
        <span class="offscreen">&nbsp;for Template Id 2,003</span>
        <span class="offscreen">&nbsp;popup</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="popover-body"></div>
    <input type="button" class="btn pull-right tooltip-hide-btn" value="hide" aria-label="Hide help for Template Id 2,003">
    <div style="width: 100%; clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

[image: example of supp help content]

What should I be using/doing? Would this be a good use case for live-regions? If so, any example code?

Comment: The button element is not a block element and is fine inside a label. This might be helpful: https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily have to be a live region.  It feels more like a modal dialog, especially if you have interactive elements in it, such as the hide button.

There's a working example of an accessible modal dialog on https://github.com/gdkraus/accessible-modal-dialog

Comment: I disagree.  Popovers are hybrids between tooltips and modals.  And I think they behave and look more like tooltips, rather than modals.  Modals hide all content until user makes an action selection.  Popovers are much less disruptive but still have interactive elements inside.

Comment: They can both be disruptive and both can be dismissed by tapping or clicking outside the element. They’re all conceptually the same.